# Decision hierarchy of the empire at the death star

Tags: star-wars

What was the formal chain of command at the death star and within the Empire? Could Grand Moff Tarkin give an order to Darth Vader or The Emperor, or who was superior to who?

Comment: The Emperor liked the decision-making tree to be loose. They both reported directly to the boss and neither was technically capable of ordering the other